# Home page does not show 5 post , only 2 of latest post are displayed ( Show 5 post on main page is already set)

Tags: blogger

Recently does not show all 5 post on blogger home page even "Show 5 nos post on home page" is already set . Last Four days I posted 4 new blog each day with same label . I noticed only 2 post (1st & 2nd) are showing on my home page but 3 post (3rd, 4th & 5th) are missing. when I clicked on next page , sixth to tenth post is there. when I clicked that particular label , only 2 post ( same as home page) are showing even I set " `?max-results=5`  " but when clicked on " Older Post" then all post with same label displayed. ( Link : http://sanzuu.blogspot.com & Label : MOBILE)

Comment: include the link to your blog

Comment: @simr its http://sanzuu.blogspot.com

Comment: can you tell me what is the number of posts per page set in `dashboard > settings > Posts and comments`. is it also 5 or 2?

Comment: @simr nos of post on the main page is 6

Comment: The blog posts are being directly pasted from Microsoft Word , this can cause problems as Word has a lot of hidden formatting which interferes with the functioning of the Blogger (like problems with number of posts per page being different from settings , problem with feed ,etc). One solution to this is that  when copying from Word , copy first to HTML mode of the post editor (not the Compose mode) and then switch to Compose mode to apply text customization (like bold , italics , etc). If you use Chrome , you can Use Ctrl+Shift+V to paste into Blogger (This pastes by removing any formatting)

Comment: @Prayag Verma Thanks for very intelligent answer. Now I am using html table instead of Ms Word format and feeling happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog posts are being directly pasted from Microsoft Word , this can cause problems as Word has a lot of hidden formatting which interferes with the functioning of the Blogger ( like problems with number of posts per page being different from settings , problem with feed ,etc ). One solution to this is that when copying from Word , copy first to HTML mode of the post editor (not the Compose mode) and then switch to Compose mode to apply text customization ( like bold , italics , etc ). If you use Chrome , you can Use Ctrl+Shift+V to paste into Blogger  ( This pastes by removing any formatting )   -– Prayag Verma